# Why does the power series expansion of $f(z) = e^{\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{z^{j}}{j}}$ have all coefficients positive?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why does the power series expansion of $f(z) = e^{\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{z^{j}}{j}}$ have all coefficients positive?($k$ is some fixed integer)

$f(z)=e^{\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{z^{j}}{j}}$ is an entire function so it has a power series expansion at $0$, $f(z)= \sum_na_nz^{n}$, now I claim that all $a_n$ are positive. Why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to see this.

One is just to do the substitution.

Let's write $\sum_{1}^{k} \frac{z^j}{j}=zq(z)$ where $q(z)$ is a polynomial with all positive coefficients. Then:

$$e^{zq(z)}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^nq(z)^n}{n!}$$

Because of that $z^n$, we see that the coefficient of $z^N$ in $e^{zq(z)}$ is the same as the coefficients of $z^N$ in the polynomial:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{z^nq(z)^n}{n!}$$

But that polynomial can be easily shown to have only positive coefficients since $q(z)$ only has positive coefficients.

---

Alternatively, you can see it via the chain rule. If $p(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{z^j}{k}$ then we prove by induction that:

$$f^{(n)}(z) = e^{p(z)}q_n(z)$$

Where $q_n(z)$ is a polynomial with has only positive coefficients. (Specifically, we get that $q_{n+1}(z)=p'(z)q_n(z)+q_n'(z)$.) So, in particular:

$$f^{(n)}(0)> 0$$

---

More generally:

Given $g(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_iz^i$ and $h(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} b_jz^j$ where $a_i>0$ and $b_1>0$ and all other $b_j\geq 0$, then define $f(z)=g(h(z))$. Then we can show inductively that $f^{(n)}(0)>0$ for all $n$.

It's a little more arduous to prove, since we used the nice property of $g(z)=e^z$ that $g'(z)=g(z)$. The "substitution" argument works just as well, however.

This is not always true when $h(0)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

In a combinatorial flavor, $n!$ times the coefficient of $z^n$ in
$$ \exp\left(z+\ldots+\frac{z^k}{k}\right) $$
is the number of permutations in $S_n$ that decompose in disjoint cycles with length $\leq k$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics)).
Then it is quite trivial that the previous coefficient is rational and non-negative.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer too!

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$ f(z)=\exp\Big(z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{z^k}{k}\Big)=e^{z}e^{\frac{z^2}{2}}\cdots e^{\frac{z^k}{k}}$$

Therefore the power series for $f$ about $z=0$ can be computed from the power series of $e^{\frac{z^j}{j}}$, $1\leq j\leq k$, using the Cauchy product. As the coefficients of the power series of $e^{\frac{z^j}{j}}$ are positive, it follows that the coefficients of the series for $f$ are positive as well.

Alternately, you can substitute $\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{z^j}{j}$ into the power series for $e^z$,  use the multinomial theorem, then interchange the sums.